# Can't concatenate on an array - Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php, arrays, syntax-error, concatenation

Why can't I use this concatenation `FILEPATH . 'assets/uploads/'` in an array ???

```
$upload = array(
        'path'  =>  FILEPATH . 'assets/uploads/', // Get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'
        'allowed_types' =>  'gif|jpg|png'
    );
```

I get a syntax error: *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'*

Comment: The problem is somewhere else http://3v4l.org/8RYLk

Comment: It isn't a logic error, but syntax. Is something that php doesn't understand??

Comment: Correct. But you have to post code that actually triggers the error.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario You were right! i put the array inside a method and worked! You shouldn't remove your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the concatenation is not working when the array is in a class, but outside a method.

```
class Foo {
$upload = array(
        'path'  =>  FILEPATH . 'assets/uploads/', unexpected '.', expecting ')'
        'allowed_types' =>  'gif|jpg|png'
    );
}
```

You have to set it inside a method in order to work

```
class Foo{
   public function daa(){
        $this->upload = array(
            'path'  =>  FILEPATH . 'assets/uploads/', unexpected '.', expecting ')'
            'allowed_types' =>  'gif|jpg|png'
        );
   }
}
```